# Deploy Knowledge article from one org to another

Tags: knowledge, lightning-knowledge

My requirement is to move Knowledge articles from Production to Dev. When I am searching for options, all articles are pointing to Export with Translation.(which I dont need)

Also I dont see any  export option under Data Management.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdfWeUAJ/move-knowledge-articles-from-one-org-to-another

This article tells that this may be still in idea stage.

Can anyone provide inputs?

Comment: see also vendor solutions like [Gearset](https://docs.gearset.com/en/articles/2451694-knowledge-articles)

Answer (score 0):

A workaround you can try using [third-party](https://kbapps-1b0d72f037e5.herokuapp.com/) tool hosted on the Heroku platform that helps to export/import knowledge articles from salesforce.

Check steps to export/import knowledge articles [here](https://www.codekiat.com/2020/04/export-knowledge-articles-salesforce.html).